# BigCommerce product update not returning image array

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a large catalog where we update products on a regular basis.
The product update works, and returns the product and other arrays except for images.
Existing images are updated and new images are added, but the responseMessage does not contain the image array. I can create a workaround, but it would not as graceful as handling a single product object.

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PutAsync(String.Format("catalog/products/{0}", product.BigCommerceProductId), httpContent);

Answer (score 0):

If you add a query on your request to include images, this should resolve the issue.

Try something like:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store-hash}}/v3/catalog/products/{product_id}?include=images
```